# How to create my own libraries to get started with an OS?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I am learning OS concepts. I created a simple boot loader in ASM and a looping kernel file in C. I compiled them both and it works.

Now I need to print some text using kernel, which is in C. I learnt that while on developing an OS, usage of standard library functions must be omitted. So how can I create my own library. I mean to print a text to screen without including any standard header file. How can I do that? Should I use inline assembly or any other methods?

Making it so simple, my question is, How C language can interact with the hardware without standard libraries?

Comment: Simple answer: by talking to the hardware directly. Other answers will be overly broad

Comment: That's not an answer but my question

Comment: That is exactly the answer. You take documentation and start accessing the hardware you want accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I do the same 15 years ago :) ,  you are forced to use your own kernel functions, based in the HAL concept (hardware abstraction layer).  You build a HAL based module, as an example, a screen output driver. This driver should be built with two sides:  The side who is in contact with your own custom OS, and the side who is in contact with your very specific hardware.  So, if at any given moment you change the hardware then your OS is not affected by this change. This is called (formal) : Interface. Is a software pattern concept.
Good look. is a very intersting project :)

As a pseudo code example:

```
// yourclientprogram.c
include "screendriver.h"
i = new instance of LCDScreenDriver;
i.selectScreen(0);
i.printf("%s","hello");
```

So, your kernel files will looks like this:

```
//screendriver.h
class LCDScreenDriver extends ScreenDriver {
    protected function output(data){
         ...very specific ASM code for your LCD monitor goes here..
         ...this code is very specific to output a -data- buffer
         ...and nothing more than this  
    }
}

class ScreenDriver {
   protected function output(data); // a virtual pure function

   public function printf(args,...){
       dataTobePrinted = ..make your own printf methods...
       this.output(dataToBePrinted);
   }
}
```

Comment: So writing my own driver in C. How do I accomplish it without standard libraries. Using inline assembly in C?

Comment: You should select a subset of that standard libraries, only those that has no dependencies to external code or other libraries designed for a very specific os.